# phpunit with netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I tried following [**this tutorial**](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html); I got up to step 5.5-6 but I get this error

```
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.


Fatal error: Class 'Calculator' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line ...
```

Now I realize that I can just include/require the file in, but is there any way to tell Netbeans/PHPUnit to always include in the test file, the file that `phpunit-skelgen` generated from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either include the class to be tested yourself in the testclass, like you write, or you use a bootstrap file to handle loading the class to test  through autoloading for instance. I think [this tutorial](http://jes.st/2011/phpunit-bootstrap-and-autoloading-classes/) will give you lots of pointers about why and how to use a bootstrap with PHPUnit.

Personally, my bootstrap sets up the testdatabase, some configuration settings, the autoloading mechanism for the application to test and then starts the application I want to test.